# How to add or call external command to wix custom action?

Tags: wix

I am having trouble executing the script for the dism command on the custom action. The cmd will just pop up and no execution upon installation of the MSi.

My script look like this:

Any idea or suggestion might help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

I am expecting to execute or run this dism command during the installation of my MSI executable file.

Comment: <CustomAction Id="CallDismCommand" Directory="$(var.ComponentDirectory64)_Graphics_igcc" ExeCommand="Dism /Online /Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackagePath:(path)" Execute="immediate" Return="check" Impersonate="no"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence><Custom Action="CallDismCommand" Before="InstallInitialize"/></InstallExecuteSequence>

Here is my script by the way